# Reading an url and returning the url of a website that contains a string n times

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

i have to do this exercise for college. Basically i have to make a function findurls(urls,s,k) where urls is a list of urls, s is a string and n is the times that string has to appear in order to return the url. For example if i have urls in my list that contain the string "Python" at least two times, the function should return me only the urls from the list that have the string "Python" occur 2 times or more. I wrote this code:

```
def findurl(urls,s,k):
    count = 0
    for url in urls:
    f =  ul.urlopen(url)
    r = f.read()
    if s in url:
    count += 1
    if count <= k:
    return url
```

Unfortunately, it returns only a single url, but i know for sure that at least 4 urls on my list have the string 'Python' occur at least 2 times. How do i fix this?

Edit: i've fixed my code thanks to your suggestions, like this:

def findurl(urls,s,k):

```
 ...:     for url in urls:
 ...:       f =  ul.urlopen(url)
 ...:       r = f.read()
 ...:       for s in url:
 ...:         count = url.count(s)
 ...:       if count >= k:
 ...:        return url
 ...:
 ...:
```

and now it works...somewhat. It doesn't return the http://www.python.org/ that has many 'Python' strings. Should i convert the urls to text, encode them?

Comment: Hint,  `string.count(substring)` will tell you how many times a substring is in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework question, I haven't provided you with any code, just some suggestions and ways to fix your code.

There are a few things I see wrong with your code. By my understanding, you want to count the number of times a string appears in another string. Your code does not do this right not, it counts how many urls have `s` in them.

Also, I think your `<=` should be `>=`. Currently as long as your `k` is greater than 0, this will always return on the first iteration.

Thirdly, you do not save multiple matching urls. In this specific case, I would recomend you look at list comprehensions or the `filter` function. With either of these, you could make this with 2 lines of code, including the `def` line.

Comment: It's not a graded homework, just an exercise to see if i get it on my lecture slides, unfortunately i do not. I've tried changing the > symbol and using string.count(substring), but it returns nothing now. I can't use filter as i have to do it with everything i've studied 'till this lesson, and we haven't done the filter function yet.

Comment: Have you used list comprehensions? A list comprehension would be perfect in this case. Remember, list comprehensions can be written in the form `[bar(foo) for foo in foos if condition(foo)]` where `condition(foo)` is any expression that returns a boolean.